# Converting code from Matlab to C?

Tags: c, matlab, entropy

I need to write a code that will:

> Read a file that is a source and it is "emitting" 8-bytes signs (letters, numbers). The code needs to add +1 in the accumulator that is the size of 2^8^n every time a sign occurs. After I can calculate the entropy. The input parameters are the file and "n" that is 8 bytes * n (from 3 to 5).

Example:

> if we read from file `10001110|11110000|11111111|00001011|10101010`, for n = 3, we put +1 in the accumulator at `100011101111000011111111` and proceed with +1 at `111100001111111100001011` and so on...

The main problem is speed of this process. I need to read files that are max 50MB. Programming language can be anything from C, Matlab or Java.

Code so far in Matlab for n = 1. I need a good implementation for accumulator, so its not ful size from the very beginning...

```
load B.mat; %just some small part of file
file = dec2bin(B);
file = str2num(file);
[fileSize, ~] = size(file);
%Choose n
n = 1;

%Make accumulator
acu10 = linspace(0, 2^8^n-1, 2^8^n);
acu = dec2bin(acu10);
acu = str2num(acu);
index = zeros(size(acu10))';

%go through file and add +1 in accumulator
    for i = 1:n:fileSize
        for j = 1:size(acu)

        if acu(j,:) == file(i);
            index(j) = index(j) + 1;
        end

    end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This website's purpose is to help you with programming problems, not do the work for you. What have you tried? Where have you failed?

Comment: Show what you have done in the language of your choice, and explain what problems you are having with the speed, including numbers. For large high-entropy files and high `n` you will have memory problems, unless you can resolve your entropy calculation as you go. 50MB max should be fine though.

Comment: @Neil why memory problems. The way I see it, you can accumulate max 2^64 increments in a 64-bit unsigned integer, so a file can be 2^64 bytes long, no?

Comment: @rubenvb: The OP's implied algorithm requires storage of a counter against each found value. For files with high entropy, and for values of `n`  greater than a moderate limit, this is going to be of the same order as slurping the whole file to RAM. For small values of `n`, you just need the counter to be able to cope in case whole file is same bytes repeated e.g. for n=1, processing a huge file still only requires a few KB.

Comment: @Neil ok, I guess I'm misunderstanding the algorithm then.